# PHP delete function doesn't redirect to header location, but deletes entry

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to create a function that deletes an entry with a certain device id and product id.The function deletes the row but runs the else statement with an error.
mysqli_affected_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysql

The function must also redirect to dashboard.php but doesn't. Any help will be appreciated.

```
if(isset($_POST['remove_product'])){

    //recieve input
    $DeviceID = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['DeviceID']);
    $productID = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['productID']);

    $name = $_SESSION['username'];


    $sql="DELETE FROM products WHERE deviceid = '$DeviceID' AND productid = '$productID' AND username = '$name'";
    $resultsql = mysqli_query($db,$sql);


    if($resultsql != FALSE && mysqli_affected_rows($resultsql) == 1){

            echo "Device/Product is deleted!";
            header('Location: dashboard.php');
            exit;
          }

    else{
        echo "Device/Product not registered";

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to call `mysqli_affected_rows($db)` with the `$db` link parameter, not with the `$resultsql` variable, which is a boolean as the result of a DELETE query. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Comment: `$resultsql != FALSE`  as well. It should be `$resultsql !== FALSE`. (`=` equals assigning, `==` equals comparing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A much better idea would be to use a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.prepare.php), [bind the `$DeviceID`, `$productID` and `$name` parameters](http://php.net/manual/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) then check [`$stmt->affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php)

```
// Exceptions are much easier to deal with
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$stmt = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM products WHERE deviceid = ? AND productid = ? AND username = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('iis', $_POST['DeviceID'], $_POST['productID'], $_SESSION['username']);
$stmt->execute();
if ($stmt->affected_rows === 1) {
    // and so on.
```

Answer (score 2):

**mysqli_affected_rows()** should refernce the connection not the query. [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_affected_rows.asp)

Further you cannot user **header** after an **echo** statement [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

See the updated code (NOT TESTED)

```
if(isset($_POST['remove_product'])){

    //recieve input
    $DeviceID = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['DeviceID']);
    $productID = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['productID']);

    $name = $_SESSION['username'];


    $sql="DELETE FROM products WHERE deviceid = '$DeviceID' AND productid = '$productID' AND username = '$name'";
    $resultsql = mysqli_query($db,$sql);


    if($resultsql && mysqli_affected_rows($db) == 1){
            header('Location: dashboard.php');
            exit;
          }

    else{
        echo "Device/Product not registered";

    }

}
```

Comment: Great point about not using `echo` before `header`, I totally missed that

Answer (score -1):

Try replace

```
mysqli_affected_rows($resultsql) to mysqli_affected_rows($db)
```

Comment: If `$db` wasn't working, then the delete wouldn't happen either, but the OP clearly said the delete was still happening.

Comment: Try replace  mysqli_affected_rows($resultsql) to  mysqli_affected_rows($db)